# How can I replace the imp module in existing code to load .pyc files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-importlib

I am doing a CS course from the MIT Open Courseware website that has been taped in 2016 (course 6.0002 - intro to computational thinking and data science).
In one of the problem sets (ps3) the staff provided a test.py file and a bunch of .pyc files.

One of the first lines in the test file is:

```
import imp

test = imp.load_compiled("test", "test.pyc")
```

My pycharm compiler says that the imp module is discontinued since Python 3.4 and that I should move on to `importlib`.

I can't find in the documentation, nor in the internet what function in `importlib` replace this exact function of `imp`.

I found a similar question with no replies and answers here: [Using importlib to load compiled modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64178027/using-importlib-to-load-compiled-modules)

Comment: Have you tried just using `import test` while the `test.pyc` file is placed in a directory that is in `sys.path` (e.g. in the same directory as the script you are running)?

Comment: `imp` is deprecated, not removed.  It will still work.

Comment: Although, .pyc files are byte code specific to a version of Python, so you may need to install the version of Python the course was designed for.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I tried to run it using python 3.8, but an error fired saying i should replace imp. I thought about changing the interpeter to 3.4, but I already solved 2 problem sets on the same project using python 3.8 so i prefer not to change it midway to prevent potential errors.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I have now tried importing test as you suggested with test.pyc in the same directory of the script im trying to run. Now i get ImportError which i dont understand:
`import test
ImportError: bad magic number in 'test': b'\x16\r\r\n'`
Remember that test.pyc is a binary so i cannot inspect it for errors of any kind

Comment: @Aqua- That's because the .pyc is compiled by a *specific* version of Python.  You have to install the version of Python it was generated for as I mentioned in my second comment.  Also the `imp` "error" should be a DeprecationWarning (that's what I get at the console, maybe PyCharm stops you) and it isn't fatal.  But using the wrong version of Python *is fatal* for your issue. If you don't have the original source, your only option is to install the version of Python that the .pyc was generated on.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Got it. The problem now is that pycharm doesnt support python 3.4. From the jetbrain help manual:
`PyCharm supports the following versions of Python:

Python 2: version 2.7

Python 3: from the version 3.6 up to the version 3.10`
Any more ideas as to how i can use this test file?

Comment: @Aqua- don't use PyCharm   I've heard there are tools to reverse a .pyc back to a .py.  Then you could generate a .pyc for a newer version of Python.  Google `decompile pyc`

Comment: @MarkTolonen I ended up decompiling the test file and like you suggested, then importing it as mkrieger suggested and it works now.
before that i tried with all my might to install python 3.4 and run the script from terminal, but i ended up getting the same error as before.
Anyway you may write a solution i will aprove it

Comment: The .pyc wasn’t from Python 3.4 then. The MIT course didn’t specify?

Comment: I think they specified in an earlier course exactly what version they are using, but didnt think it matter. i thought that since py3.4 can work with the imp module it should do the trick...

Comment: @Aqua- No pyc files are compiled byte code for an exact version of Python. The imp module has nothing to do with it. The imp module is only deprecated and works in all versions of Python, but importing byte code requires the exact version of Python that compiled it.

Comment: @Aqua- I'm doing the same course and running into the same problem. Would it be possible to share the files that you have decompiled? The packages uncompyl6 and decompyle3 that I tried to use don't work with the newest version of python. Also I can't get my IDE (Spyder) to use the python 3.5 interpreter.